Problem deploying report server (asks for login and password)
I created a report server project. Added shared datasource and for reports added datasource which uses shared datasource and a dataset. I try to deploy server, but I asks for login and password. I saw many similar questions but still can't solve the problem.
I tried to set credentials for shared datasouce as

Use Windows Authentication - it still asks for login and password.
Do not use credentials - it asks for log and pas
Use this user name and password - and put some user name and password in there. When i deployed server, i entered this log and pass and it asks me again.
In SSRS_Report project I tried to set OverriteDatasets and OverriteDataSources to true and false, no difference. In TargetServerUrl I put link from Report Server Configuration Manager  - http://MY_Computer_Name/ReportServer


I also tried to enter as login and password log and pas of a user form MS Sql Server, doesn't help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
